# Is there a distinction in naming conventions amongst certain design patterns?

Tags: design-patterns

MVC, MVVM, Smart UI and Three-Tier are referred to as design patterns, but so are abstract factory, singleton, and decorator. However, the former set relates to the overall architectural layout of the program whereas the latter set deals with interactions/relationships between classes or objects. 
What vocabulary is used to differentiate the two? Architectural design patterns vs class-level design patterns, for example?

Answer (score 0):

Design patterns such as Singleton, Decorator,... are called GoF (Gand of Four) design patterns which are basic design patterns and are originally introduced in a book in 1995.

After that many design patterns developed for different problems such as MVC and MVVM which are designed to solve a specific and common problem in UI.

Actually MVVM is not an architectural pattern. The term architectural patterns refer to other patterns which are solving problems in software architecture. such as SOA and Microservices.